# Windows Onecare Backups with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, backup

I've got 4 months of Windows Onecare Backup files from a Vista installation.  I've upgraded the computer to Windows 7 (and uninstalled Onecare since it's not compatible) and I'm now just using Windows Backup.

Are the Onecare backups worth keeping around? The format looks close (directory structure, etc) but if I can't just open them with Windows Backup I'm not really interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that it's possible but kinda painful:

http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/onecarebackupandrestore/thread/ed189402-665c-4785-a49c-e7fe6384f6be

Have to open the archive with a 3rd party program (7zip, etc) and get the files out.  I may just delete the set.